# Question about domain in 2 dimensional analysis

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

In a problem set I have been asked the following question:

Does $f(x,y)=3x+3y$ have a maximum or minimum value on $\mathbb{R}$ without any constraints?

Very easy question indeed. But my issue is: should the domain not be $\mathbb{R}^2$? Or is the question formulated correctly since the function $f$ is of type $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You're probably right, if you want to be 100% sure ask the source.

Comment: The domain is obviously $\mathbb R^2$ which makes it an obvious typo. Has this function maximum or minimum value without any constraints?

Comment: No obviously not, since $x$ and $y$ can be chosen arbitrarily large or small.